# Android Navigation Drawers and Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have just created a new project using Eclipse and the Android SDK. The project now contains a blank activity with navigation drawers and its sample 3 navigation items.

Under `res/layout`, I currently have `activity_main.xml`, `fragment_main.xml` and `fragment_navigation_drawer.xml`.

My question is -- to display different content based on what is chosen in the navigation drawer, do I make a new view that will be loaded in place of the `fragment_main.xml`, or do I load the view inside of `fragment_main.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new layout for each `Fragment` items if `Fragment views` are different

When an drawer item is selected, replace the fragment in the activity.

So your activity layout  should have , `Drawer as parent layout` and a `FrameLayout container` and `ListView` as child.

When an item is selected, replace the `Fragment` in the container of `Activity Layout`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the layout to be the same you don't have to replace `fragment_main.xml` because that's your layout file for your fragment. If your layout is different in each fragment. You have to create a different layout file and load it with your Fragment class.

But again if your layout of the fragments is the same you just have to "refill" your `fragment_main.xml` with new content.

I hope i cleared it a bit up for you